# How to replace min values in an array?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python and do not know the terminology or syntax very well.

I am attempting to assign all minimum values in an array to `1` if it is the min value and `0` if not.

I have attempted:

```
numpy.minimum(Drug, Size, Strength, Intake Form, variable, /, out=None, *, where= if True=1 else=0)
```

The value variable is `price` and I am omitting the variable `firm` for the `min` function.  Each array is characterized by `drug`, `size`, `strength`, `intake form` and variable and I want replace the price of each firm with a `1` if it is lowest and `0` if not.

How would I go about writing this code?

Comment: Please read through [ask] and post a [mcve] question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of several possible ways.

```
import numpy as np


def min_mask(arr):
    m = np.min(arr)
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: x == m)(arr).astype(int)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_arr = np.array([-1, -2, -6, -4, -5, -1, -1, -6, -1])
    print(min_mask(my_arr))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```